# How can I add \n to a file without adding a newline?

Tags: python, newline

I am working on a project to improve my python skills on file saving when this happened:

(I am writing an example):

```
    appND = """inp = input("Type enter to run")
open('file.py', 'x').write('print("Hi,\n\n I am confused")')"""
```

When I ran the program it saved this to the file:

```
print("Hi,

I am confused")
```

This would not be a problem but I want to publish a **300** lines long file with a recovery script to recover the original file which saves specific numbers to a **.txt** file, but every time I run the recovery **.py** file, There are **EOL** errors.

I hope that an advanced programmer helps me with this...

Comment: '\n' is a new line/linefeed character... It sounds like you're asking how to add a newline without adding a newline.

Comment: If you want to display, `\n` then you can escape it, like, `\\n`.

Comment: It is not clear to me what it is that you wnat. Can you elaborate on how the eventual file should look like and what recovery.py contains?

Comment: You can add an `r` prefix to prevent the `\n`s from being turned into a newlines. i.e. `r"""inp = input("Type enter to run")…"""`

Comment: You don't want to write out to the file a newline, but rather a backslash followed by a 'n'. To write out a backslash, you need to escape it with another backslash, hence: "\\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another backslash () before to make it work

```
d = "i love '\\n' python."
print(d)
```